# Reading XML tags using PHP to create a table

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, html-table

I have and XML file which is constructed like so:

```
<Row>
<Cell><Data>Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Surname</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Email</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell><Data>Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Surname</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Email</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell><Data>Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Surname</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Email</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell><Data>Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Surname</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>Email</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

What I want to do is add them to a table using PHP so far I have written this code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom -> load("file.xml");
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Data'); 
echo( "<table><tr>");
foreach( $data as $node){ echo( "<td>". $node -> textContent . "<td>");}
echo( "</tr></table>");

?>
```

The problem is that its appending all the data to td tags which get really long and what I need it to do is add a tr tag after the 3 data tags that are read.

Its currently creating something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td>
<td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td>
<td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td>
<td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need it to be

```
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td></tr>
</table>
```

HELP! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `for` loop a bit:

```
$n = 0;
foreach($data as $node)
{ 
    if($n % 3 == 0) { echo '<tr>'; }
    echo( "<td>". $node -> textContent . "<td>");
    if(++$n % 3 == 0) { echo '</tr>'; }
}
```

And remove the opening and closing `tr`'s that you already have in there

Comment: PERFECT SOLUTION WORKED FIRST TIME MANY THANKS :-)

Answer (score 0):

This involves a simple edit to your code. As you want it to appear **for** every **third entry**, you just need to move the `<tr>` inside the loop.

This should solve your problem:

```
<?php
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom -> load("file.xml");
    $data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Data'); 

    $counter = 0; // Set the entry counter

    echo( "<table>");

    foreach($data as $node) {
        if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        echo "<td>". $node -> textContent . "<td>";

        if($counter % 3 == 0) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        $counter++; // Increment the counter
    }

    echo( "</table>");
?>
```

It's not the cleanest code, but should work.